# What form should the $query media query array have for an Elementor page builder function?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, array

I'm building a theme with the Elementor page builder and I want to add some CSS output to certain elements. I hooked into the parse_css function.

I want to use the stylesheet::add_rules() function ([code reference](https://code.elementor.com/methods/elementor-stylesheet-add_rules/)). This function takes three parameters:

```
Stylesheet::add_rules( string $selector, array|string $style_rules = null, array $query = null )
```

The first parameters, the `$selector` and the `$style_rules` are not so difficult:

```
     $post_css->get_stylesheet()->add_rules( $element->get_unique_selector(), [
    'width' => '300px',
   ] );
```

This is an example function where the element gets a width of 300px. The difficult thing here is the media query, `$query`. I know that parameter wants an array as input, but it doesn't tell what *kind* of array or in which form.

I tried a lot of things. These are a few I thought logical:

```
    $query = ['(min-width: 600px)'];
    $query = ['@media (min-width: 600px)'];
    $query = [
    'min-width' => '600px',
   ];
```

The last one has the same form as the `$style_rules` parameter, but it doesn't work.

I searched for examples, documentation, Github etc., all to no avail.

How can  I change my `$query` input parameter so that the code is rendered with a media query?

Many thanks if you can provide me with an example!

Comment: Try `$query = [ 'min' => 600 ];` ? But note, I don't use Elementor, so I was just guessing (based on their code).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I still doesn't work completely, but we're not further than first. Current output: `@media(min-width:px) {
 .elementor-element-7a8d1c4 {
  width:300px;
 }
 .elementor-element-0d5248a {
  width:300px;
 }
}`. I tried `'600'`, `'600px'` and `600` but those all give the same results. When I change it to `max => 600`, I get a max-width output with 767px (first breakpoint). My guess now is that it works with preregistered 'devices' and not with numbers/custom queries.

Comment: Actually, I think you should try calling `add_device()` before the `add_rules()`: `add_device( '600', 600 )`. Then the `'min' => 600` should work. There might be a better way, though.

Comment: You're a real genius Sally! And that without using Elementor. It works like a charm (`$post_css->get_stylesheet()->add_device( '600', 600 );`). Thanks! Add it as an answer ;-)

Comment: PS: I just tested that it doesn't work for `'max'`. I don't know why, but anyway, I do know how the Elementor developers 'think'.

Comment: I hope my answer helps?

Comment: Yes, for sure it helps. Thank you so much for researching this all! You’re certainly more experienced that you understand how the has functions work and what kind of input it requires. Thank you

Comment: *Writing* the answer was actually harder than researching the class! :D But anyway, good luck!

Comment: Haha thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110604/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-ralphsmit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preface

- **There's no WordPress-specific stuff in this answer**, but I'm just trying to help since the official documentation is (as of writing) not very helpful..
- But as I said in the comments, I don't use Elementor, which means I don't know much about Elementor's technical stuff. ( Even the non-technical ones, actually.. :) )

### The `$query` needs a `min`/`max` and a "device"

So the `add_rules()` method in the Elementor's [stylesheet class](https://code.elementor.com/classes/elementor-stylesheet/) is using the `add_query_hash()` and `hash_to_query()` methods in the same class, then I checked the source and noticed that:

1. The `$query` array (the 3rd parameter for the `add_rules()` method) should have a `min` or `max` item, e.g. `'min' => 600` or `'max' => 799`, or both.
2. There needs to be a "device" named the same as the `min`/`max` value in the `$query` array. And for registering a custom "device", you can use the `add_device()` method in that class.
3. Additionally, the `max` value in the `$query` array must be within the range of the device sizes. For example in the below sample, the `max` is `799`, so the max device size must be `800` or more.

### Code I used for testing the `add_rules()`:

*Tested working, but not tried with the actual Elementor plugin.*

```php
$css = new Stylesheet;

$css->add_device( '600', 600 );
$css->add_device( '800', 800 );

// Outputs @media(min-width:600px){#foo{width:300px;}}
$css->add_rules( '#foo', [
  'width' => '300px',
], [
  'min' => 600,
] );

// Outputs @media(max-width:799px){#foo{height:400px;}}
$css->add_rules( '#foo', [
  'height' => '400px', // this is merely a test
], [
  'max' => 799,
] );

echo $css; // echoes the CSS media queries above
// It works because the class has a __toString() method.
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Small update: I can confirm that all the above code works with the actual Elementor plugin (v2.9.9).